# How to upload pdf and docx file to server from app main bundle?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift4

How to upload the docx, pdf file to server from app main bundle?

```
import UIKit


    class UploadFileController: UIViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()


        }

    var path:String!
        func uploadfiletoserver(){
            path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "mahaligamResume", ofType: "pdf")
            print(path)
            if let url = URL(string: "https://www.happylifeapps.com/webservices/applyforjobs"){
                var request = URLRequest(url: url)
                let boundary:String = "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"
                // let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:myUrl! as URL);
                request.httpMethod = "POST"
                request.timeoutInterval = 10
                request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


                var dataFile: Data = Data()
                do{
                    dataFile = try NSData.init(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path, isDirectory: true)) as Data
                }catch{
                    print(error)
                }
                if(dataFile==nil)  { return; }
                let postJobData:[String:Any] = ["UserId":"1000","JobId":"jobs_14","ResumeOption":"New","CurrentCTC":"12000","PreferredCTC":"15000","CurrentLocation":"Bangalore","PreferredLocation":"Bangalore","Experience":"0","CCTC_sym":"1000","PCTC_sym":"900"]

                request.httpBody = createBodyWithParameters(parameters: postJobData, filePathKey: "Resume", FileData: dataFile as NSData , boundary: boundary) as Data
                let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
                    data, response, error in
                    print(data)
                    print(response)

                    if error != nil {
                        print("error=\(error)")
                        return
                    }else if let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue){
                        print("****** response data = \(responseString)")
                        do {
                            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary
                            print(json)

                            let status = json!["Success"] as! String
                            let errMessage = json!["Message"] as? String
                            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                                if status == "1"{
                                    print(errMessage)

                                }else{
                                    print(errMessage)
                                }
                            }

                        }catch{
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }

                }; task.resume()
            }
    }
        func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: [String: Any]?, filePathKey: String?, FileData: NSData, boundary: String) -> NSData {

            let body = NSMutableData();

            if parameters != nil {
                for (key, value) in parameters! {
                    body.appendString(string:"--\(boundary)\r\n")
                    body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
                    body.appendString(string: "\(value)\r\n")
                }
            }


            let filename = path
            let mimetype = "pdf/docx"

            body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
            body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
            body.appendString(string: "Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
            body.append(FileData as Data)
            body.appendString(string: "\r\n")
            body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)--\r\n")

            return body

        }


    }
    extension NSMutableData {

        func appendString(string: String) {
            let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
            append(data!)
        }
    }
```

I tried to upload pdf file to server from my app main bundle . but i did not get any error while uploading , but i am getting error when i am getting response from server like

```
 Message = "The resume must be a file of type: docx, doc or pdf.";
    Success = 0;
```

The backend team is stating it's a coding mistake, but I don't know where I am making a mistake. Please help me out with this issue.

Comment: please solve my issues.

Comment: In `createBodyWithParameters` method, you have the constant `mimetype` set to "pdf/docx". I assume you would need to have the correct mime type for the type of file you are uploading. Try putting the right one in for a .pdf and see if that helps.

Comment: ok sir , but i need to upload different file depends upon the user selection . so how can i declare the docx, doc and pdf in mime type

Comment: From your code it looks like you are uploading the file from your main bundle so at some point you would know what the users input is to determine which file to upload. Is that not how you intend it to work? Or Is the user selecting a file from their device to upload?

Comment: yes the user selection it may be docx, doc  of pdf . but the thing is the mime type declaration is correct or wrong i am not sure , so please help me

Comment: You can do a google search to get the correct mimetype for each file type. The mime type you have in your code is not a valid one. You will need to get the file extension of the file to upload, and then use a switch/if statement to set the correct mime type for that file.

Comment: yes sir thats true i got it now its uploading

Comment: i made mistake in filename and mimetype , now i got it

Comment: now its working fine , thanks to all developers

Comment: this is the correct t=file name and mimetype for pdf file uploading, if anyone wants this pls use this  filename = ".pdf"   mimetype = "application/pdf"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

filename and mimetype for doc file to upload to server in native api

```
  func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: [String: Any]?, filePathKey: String?, fileData: NSData, boundary: String) -> NSData {

    let body = NSMutableData();

    if parameters != nil {
        for (key, value) in parameters! {
            body.appendString(string:"--\(boundary)\r\n")
            body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
            body.appendString(string: "\(value)\r\n")
        }
    }

         filename = ".doc"
         mimetype = "application/msword"

    body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
    body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
    body.appendString(string: "Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
    body.append(fileData as Data)
    body.appendString(string: "\r\n")
    body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)--\r\n")

    return body

}
```

Comment: In same way you can change docx and pdf filename and mimetype without any changes and already i posted filename and mimetype of pdf and docx . this is perfectly working for me . please try this

Answer (score 0):

PDF:mimetype and filename for pdf file uploading

filename = ".pdf"
mimetype = "application/pdf"

DOCX: mimetype and filename for docx uploading
 filename = ".docx"
 mimetype = "application/application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"

this is worked for me ,